# CiviCRM events pay later error - Undefined index: event

Tags: civievent, paylater

I'm getting an error on submitting events where "pay later" is selected as payment method. The page times out - if I select a different payment method the next page loads OK.

This is the error I'm getting

> Notice: Undefined index: event in
>   CRM_Core_Payment_ProcessorForm::preProcess() (line 78 of
>   xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php).

Has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: I have the same behavior when I try to change "Payment Method". I've a message saying that there is a network problem, form buttons become grayed, and I have the same error message in db logs. I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.24 (updated some days ago). I've not noticed this error before this update.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to civicrm stackexhange!

Your first step is to try replicate this on - http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Configure things just like you have in your own civicrm.

And if you find you get the same error then amend your question with details/screenshots so that we can reproduce next.

Comment: I've just done a quick test on the civi sandbox, but I note that this is running version 4.7.25 - compared to the current recommended version of 4.7.23 which we are running on the site with the issue. This is not comparing like with like - the issue may be related to a bug fixed in 4.7.25.

Comment: Which is why we test on our current dmaster 

Comment: Hi Karin, are you saying that if I test this using the 4.7.25 sandbox version and I don't get the error that this then indicates that the problem is fixed in 4.7.25? If that is the case then should I update my production site to 4.7.25?

Comment: Oh no - never update production site to the latest - if you dont't get the error on dmaster demo then we know a) something has been fixed or b) it's specific to your instance - that's how we triage bugs - trying to figure out the where and when.

Comment: So, my point is that because it's a different version, you don't know whether it's a or b - so not very much better off. I've done another test on a sandbox I set up myself using 4.7.23 and that doesn't give me the error - meaning it must be something to do with that specific installation.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the civi sandbox. But I don't now why 'event' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on the civi sandbox. But I don't now why 'event' is not defined. I have these logs in drupal :
Référent    http://xxxx/index.php?q=civicrm/contact/view/participant&reset=1&id=2825&cid=6632&action=update&context=participant&selectedChild=event
Message Notice : Undefined index: event dans preProcess() (ligne 78 de /xxx/xxx/xxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php).
As workaround I've just updated line 78 : if (empty($currency) *&& !empty($form->_values['event'])*) {

Comment: updating Jquery (using jQuery Update drupal module) resolve this problem.